# Upgrade Solaris 8 Sparc to Solaris 10 Sparc with ISO Only

Tags: solaris-10

We have several Sun 100 Blades in our Software lab that are currently running Solaris 8.  Since the lifetime of Solaris 8 is running out in November, we are moving to Solaris 10.  These are SPARC stations.  Here is the problem.

These systems are old and only contain a CD R/W and not a DVD R/W.  You can download Solaris 10 SPARC ISO for DVD.  I've searched the net on how to divide the DVD into CD's with no luck.  Plus, you can no longer get Solaris 10 on CD's.  We've discussed purchasing DVD drives and replacing the CD drives, but the time to get them on dock does not meet our schedule.

I've found how to load/mount an ISO file onto a Solaris OS but when I reboot (from both reboot command and init 6) the mount goes away.  I've also found how to use one system to do a new install with the ISO.  But, I've been given permission to experiment with one station only.

Here is the question:
Is there anyway to use the ISO mounted then upgrade the Solaris 8 to 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Used an x86 Solaris VM running on RHEL and did a network install.